# No session available to complete the message with the lock token Logic app

Tags: azure, session, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

My logic app is not working and throwing below error when I pass session id for queue connector.

```
No session available to complete the message with the lock token
```

I already have enabled session while create a new queue.

[image]

Is there any other settings required to work this?

Comment: still getting same error :(

Comment: yea created same way that you showed :(

Comment: please do thanks a lot , it will be great help. waiting for your reply.

Comment: is that your logic app works fine with session ?

Comment: ohh ok please try thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Neo, I have given the solution below. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Also check that same connection is used for both message received and closed action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried replicating your flow and it's working fine to me. 
[image]

Here is my Logic App configuration
[image]

> I just want you to make sure if you have selected the "Next available" value in the **Session id** field in the Trigger. With that, your workflow should work fine.

Hope it helps!